# Two or three different user objects for a grails application with spring security core?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I'm using grails 2.1 and i've three different business objects (user objects) in my web application.

Each user object has different attributes and relationships to other domain objects.

I want each user object is able to authenticate with the web application and to get access to different screens / dashboards and so on. Some screens are available to all user objects and look the same.

To this day i just extended the User class generated by spring security core. As example:

```
class ShopOwner extends User {}
class Customer extends User {}
class Affiliate extends User {}
```

In this case i'm able to login with spring security login as ShopOwner, Customer and Affiliate without problems.

But is this the preferred way of doing this? Or should i implement this use case different? (according to UserDetailService etc.) Some suggestions, official solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Don't you want to use different Roles?

Comment: Not at this time, but maybe in future. Seperating the different kinds of user is like splitting these into different roles with different relationships and attributes. (A ShopOwner can have a shop, but a Customer can't)

Comment: Have used similar approach - no problem

Comment: I'm not sure I see an actual question here. You have a solution, but seem to be looking for discussion regarding if this is the best way to do this or if there are other ways. The Grails User mailing list is a better fit for discussions.

Comment: Thanks Igor! @cdeszaq Yes that's it. I'm looking for the best way doing this. I also look for alternatives or suggestions. Maybe this could be done by apache shiro better? Thanks for your suggestion to grails user mailing list.